How to crop url image in jupyter notebook markdown
I am using an image from an online article in a jupyter notebook, and I know how to resize the image in markdown:
<img src="https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/4ae1c74d-9819-42b7-b037-923a8a804f02/grl55223-fig-0001-m.jpg" alt="Fig 1" width=500 height=500  />

But I only want to show panel a, and was wondering if there is an easy way to crop the remote image?
I tried to use a style command:
style="width: 100px; height: 100px; object-fit: cover; object-position: 100% 0;"

But that just shrinks the plot, it doesn't crop it as I expected...
I know I can download the image and manually crop it, but I was hoping there might be a way to do it directly in markdown and only found online tips for resizing.
